# Linear Regression In the presence of second equation

Tags: regression, t-test

I have two time series $X(t)$, and $Y(t)$, both are i.i.d. I run the following linear regression model: $Y(t) = \alpha + \beta Z(t)$, where $Z(t) = X(t) + X(t-1) + X(t-2)$; The t-statistic of $\beta$ by regressing $Y(.)$ on $Z(.)$ is 2.5. Is this value correct? If not, how do I obtain the correct value?

Do you have any reading recommendations for this topic?